# Unable with an upload script that uses a version of jQuery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, upload

I'm using Bootstrap that has its own jQuery file, but I need to use the code below in my webpage to get the uploaded file's URL . The problem is, as you can see, it uses the 1.7 version of jQuery, and won't work at all with Bootstrap's version.
I'm now in front of a dilemma : if I use the 1.7 version of jQuery, the rest of the page won't appear correctly, but the script will work. If I use the last version, I'll get the exact opposite. What should I do ? Is there a mean to "translate" the code ?

Thank you in advance !

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function()
    {

    var options = { 
      beforeSend: function() 
      {
        $("#progress").show();
        //clear everything
        $("#bar").width('0%');
        $("#alerte").html("");
      $("#percent").html("0%");
      },
      uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) 
      {
        $("#bar").width(percentComplete+'%');
        $("#percent").html(percentComplete+'%');


      },
      success: function() 
      {
        $("#bar").width('100%');
        $("#percent").html('100%');

      },
    complete: function(response) 
    {
      $("#alerte").html("<font color='green'>"+response.responseText+"</font>");
    },
    error: function()
    {
      $("#alerte").html("<font color='red'> ERROR: Unable to upload the files</font>");

    }

    }; 

       $("#myForm").ajaxForm(options);

    });

    </script>
```

Comment: How about (and this isnt great) using both versions and setting one to a noconflict alias?

Answer (score 0):

If you must include multiple versions of jQuery, for instance using a plugin which depends on an earlier version, you'll want to use `$.noConflict()`.

Take a look at the [**docs here**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/), and a bit of a [**tutorial here**](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/)